# impossible to register messages in a bag file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I wrote a c++ script to send messages to a certain topic:

```
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "ros/ros.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv,"end_bag");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    
    ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise("/end",1000);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    
    std_msgs::String msg;
    msg.data = "end of loop";
    chatter_pub.publish(msg);

    //ROS_INFO("Message sent: %s",msg.data.c_str());
    while(chatter_pub.getNumSubscribers()==0){
        ros::spinOnce();
    }
    //sleep(10);
    loop_rate.sleep();
    ROS_INFO("Message sent: %s",msg.data.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

From a shell, I started recording messages sent to topic */end* :

```
rosbag record -O end /end
```

After sending of the messages, I analyzed bag file and I didn't find anything inside it.
Do you have any idea why this happens? I tried also to substitute the *while* in the code with *while(1)* but no messages is received as well.

Thanks for support.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50806/impossible-to-register-messages-in-a-bag-file/) by [Jaco](https://answers.ros.org/users/3609/jaco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jaco](https://answers.ros.org/users/3609/jaco/) on 2012-12-19**:
thanks for answer. code fortunately compiles, it was just a copy-paste error. anyway, your answer was helpful. it works. after that, i played two bag files by writing rosbag play subset.bag end.bag. the execution of first bag file should last 3.45 mins but it seems not to finish. do you know reason?

**Comment by [Jaco](https://answers.ros.org/users/3609/jaco/) on 2012-12-19**:
... moreover i can't see the usual messages count down on screen, as it happens when i play bag files one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I doubt that the code above would compile. Your advertise call specifies type std_msgs::string, the correct type is std_msgs::String though. Please read the [support guidelines](http://ros.org/wiki/Support) before posting. Always copy-paste code and tag your questions.

You publish before rosbag or any other node could register. A quick fix would be either to use a latched topic or publish right after the while loop that checks for the number of publishers to be 0.

To use a latched topic, use the following advertise call:

```
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("/end", 1000, true);
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0